# Is $D$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, field-theory

> **Problem.** Let $D$ be an integral domain and let $\mathcal{F}(D)$ be a [field of quotients](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjir5eqysDMAhVkMKYKHSnkAQkQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FField_of_fractions&usg=AFQjCNGsDslDV80jziKkdpXcKhGwh8Ik0Q) of $D$. If $D\subset \mathcal{F}(D)$ then prove or disprove that,
>
> - $D$ is a field.
> - $D=\mathcal{F}(D)$.

I tried to find counterexample to the second problem but couldn't. As for the first problem I don't know what to do. Can someone help?

Comment: Would you consider $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb Q$ to be true?

Comment: In that case, is _any_ integral domain a subset of its field of fractions? The elements of $\mathcal F(D)$ are, by definition, equivalence classes of pairs of elements of $D$, and as such an element of $D$ can _never_ be an element of $\mathcal F(D)$.

Comment: @Arthur: No. I would consider $\mathbb{Z}$ to be isomorphic to a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ provided of course you agree to call $\mathbb{Q}$ a field of quotients of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Arthur: But how can I **rigorously prove** it?

Comment: If you're that strict, then this smells more like an exercise in introductory set theory than an algebra exercice. Are you _certain_ that you are to be that strict?

Comment: @Arthur: Yes. I am *certain*.

Comment: ...by the way, if $D$ were a field then can't we prove that $\mathcal{F}(D)=D$?

Comment: No. They are _not equal_. They are canonically isomorphic, but that's how far it goes. The isomorphism sends $a \in D$ to $[(a, 1)] \in \mathcal F(D)$, but $[(a, 1)] = \{(da, d)\mid d \in D,d \neq 0\}$ is a different entity from $a$, so there can be no equality.

Comment: You must ask the instructor what to do.  Clearly what we have told you is not what you want to hear.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't instead say that $\, \mathcal{F}(D)\subset D\,$ ?

Comment: @BillDubuque: Yes.